# Kendo MVC Grid Custom Command with Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have been looking for but been unable to find a recent example of replacing the text of a grid command button with an image. I tried and older example from about 2013 but i breaks the grid which leads me to believe they have changed how the grid works since then (most likely). Does anyone know of a working example? I tried:

```
 columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Custom("ShowExceptions").Click("ShowException").Text(" ");
            command.Destroy();
        }).Width(40);
```

But the command.Destroy() does not fly.

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you add a style block with a class of .k-grid-(nameOfYourCommand) you can play with the css.

So in my example

```
<style>
    .k-grid-ShowExceptions {
        background-image: url("../../Resources/Calendar_16.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

will show a centered image of the calendar in the button.